# What is the difference between i+=d and i=i+d in Java?

Tags: java

#### Duplicate:

> [java += question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608721/java-question)
>
> [Why aren’t op-assign operators type safe in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590868/why-arent-op-assign-operators-type-safe-in-java)

When `i` is an integer and `d` is a `double`, `i+=d` works but `i= i+d` does not.

Why is this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608721/java-question.

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590868/why-arent-op-assign-operators-type-safe-in-java

Answer (score 1):

i = i + d does not work because you would be assigning a double to an int and that is not allowed.

The += operator casts the double automatically to an int, so that is why it works.

This is the link to the information on the spec:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#5304